# LaTeX updated tool for Windows 7

Tags: editors, windows, led-editor

Does some know some LaTeX tool for Windows – preferably open-source –, which is more recent than LEd, but which have the auto-complete mechanism? I use LEd for so long, but in Windows 7 I'm facing to some bugs, and the tool is not updated since 2009. A note, WinEdt and the Miktex front-end do not have the auto-complete feature (or I was not able to configure it), and LyX is not WYSIWYM.

**Update**

I tried TeXstudio and it impressive me quite well. It has the autocomplete mode (without need for typing control+space) of LEd, it has the colors of WinEdt, has the pdf viewer, the build is fast, has a log debugger. I shall switch to it (instead of LEd). Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: `MikTeX` frontend? I guess you mean `TeXWorks` (it has nothing to do with `MikTeX`). Have you had a look at `TeXMaker` or `TeXStudio` (they are cousins)

Comment: In winedt you can start a word or a command and then type "ctrl + enter" to get suggestions. You can also define "active strings". E.g. `\end{{` will automatically expand to the correct end of the current environment.

Comment: At least TeX Live's included TeXworks (0.4.3 r858 on my system) has autocompletion, and I'd expect MiKTeX's works similarly. See the Help / A short manual for TeXworks menu, section A.3 (Roots for completion). For example `bdoc` followed by the TAB key inserts `\begin{document}`, three blank lines, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think emacs has an autocomplete feature. Notepad++ does, but only if you have used that command before. TeXStudio and TeXMaker both have very good autocomplete features.

Comment: TeXNicCenter 2 has the autocomplete features using Ctrl+Space key combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used LEd until fairly recently.  Now I use [WinShell](http://www.winshell.org/) under Windows.  It has auto-complete via ctrl-space.  The auto-complete is pretty extensive, but it's also easy to customize; you just edit a text file, using a straightforward syntax.

WinShell is free but not open source.  The last release was in 2011, but it has been developed since 1998, and there have usually been releases every year or two.  It's been very stable and bug-free for me.

WinShell doesn't have a built-in PDF viewer.  I use it with [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html).  Here are typical settings for inverse search: `-reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinShell\WinShell.exe\" -c \"%f\" -l %l" "%s.pdf"`.