# How to make Adobe Reader the default PDF viewer in Winshell

Tags: windows, viewers, adobe

I am a Windows user. I use Winshell to edit Latex. In the Winshell toolbar, there is a magnifier sign labelled with `PDF`. When I click on it to view my document as PDF, it views it in GSView. I want to view it in Adobe Reader. I tried to set Adobe Reader as default program in my Windows Default Programs from the Control Panel, but this did not help. Can you help?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use Acrobat Reader with LaTeX: it locks the pdf file, and when you recompile, you have to think of closing the .pdf first. The recommended viewer for Windows is SumatraPDF, which is ultra-light (4Mo, as opposed to Adobe's monster), ultra-fast, has a 64-bit version, does not lock pdfs, and has direct and inverse search capability.

Comment: Ok. How to make Winshell opens SumatraPDF instead of GSView. Because I have the same issue. I downloaded Sumatra and WinShell still uses GSView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the `Options -> Program calls` menu and select `PDFView`. In the `exe -File` fill form, select the path to SumatraPDF.exe, as in this image:
[image]

I don't know how to configure direct search for Winshell and SumatraPDF, but I think you must find the relevant information on the web.

For inverse search, there's an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50592/latex-updated-tool-for-windows-7/50645#50645).

Answer (score 0):

For setting up WinShell for direct and inverse search, see the Winshell manual and the [FAQ at WinShell’s webside](http://www.winshell.org/faq.html). This is direct cite from the web:

> Sumatra PDF: Synchronization  « The setup is described in detail in
>   the WinShell manual.
>
> In short, please make sure, that the WinShell command line option for
>   pdflatex looks like this:
>
> ```
> -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 "%s.tex"
> ```
>
> Now, please "browse..." in the WinShell options for pdfview for the
>   sumatrapdf executable. The command line for pdfview will be set
>   automatically.
>
> In SumatraPDF... No settings at all which need to be changed
>
> Now, in WinShell, press F10, F10, F11. SumtraPDF will open with your
>   PDF.
>
> In WinShell... If you move your text cursor to a specific position and
>   press F11, SumtraPDF will jump to that specific position in the PDF
>
> In SumatraPDF... If you double click your left mouse button somewhere
>   in the text, WinShell will jump to that specific position in the tex
>   file

The setup with Sumatra is described at page 12-13 in WinShell Manual. Remember to change the path to the program files to reflect the correct path on you computer:

```
-reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\WinShell\WinShell.exe\"     -c %f -l %l" "%s.pdf"
```

If you have installed WinShell in another path than `C:\Program Files`, change to where your `winshell.exe` is located.